# Adding input files of near tool using %name% or %value% function?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, proximity, iterator

I am trying to caluclate the nearest distance between road and road_buf shp.

But I'm struggling to add input features using %name% function in NEAR TOOL.

I want to add road_buf file as "c:Desktop\road_BF\%name%_bf.shp",,,
but it does not work.

Does not NEAR TOOL provide %name% function as input ?

[image]